# What are method object functions called in JS?

Tags: javascript, json, object, methods, this

I am trying to learn JavaScript and JSON and I don't understand these lines of code. Is total a method of the object and why? What are these functions called so I can learn more about them?

```
let price = {
  dollars: 9,
  cents: 99,
  total: function () {
    return this.dollars + this.cents/100;
  }
};
```

Comment: First thing to learn about JSON, is that [object literals are not JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation).

Comment: Yes, this is a method. This can also be written as `total() { return this.dollars + ...... }` without the `: function()` part: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#method_definitions

Answer (score 1):

`let price = {}`  is called an [Object initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) using *shorthand object initialisation* in *literal notation*

- total is a *property* or *object method* of the price object

NOTE: You will not have any JSON until you JSON.stringify the object

Comment: wouldn't object initializer be all `dollars: 9, cents: 99, total: function () {return this.dollars + this.cents/100;  }` and not the only the method OP is asking?

Comment: @eis Please see update. I was not clear enough

Answer (score 0):

This function is called [**Object method**](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_methods.asp), so it is actually a method of the object.